# Equatable package can not extends class - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

I am using an extension name Dart data class generator and I allow it to use equatable package but for some reason it gave me this error [image]
[image]
The error on the import line is :"Unused import: 'package:equatable/equatable.dart'.
Try removing the import directive."

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet instead of code-image that will reproduce the error? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you show us the code behind the error dialog?

Comment: And what warning do you get from the import line?

Comment: The waring on the import line is :"Unused import: 'package:equatable/equatable.dart'.
Try removing the import directive."

Comment: DDCG does not need Equatable.  It puts its own code in for that, and better than Equatable can do.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add props override, try this:

```
class BaseCustom extends Equatable {
  final int? status;
  ...

  BaseCustom({this.status, ...});
  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object> get props =>[status, and other variable];
}
```